# ASP.NET Framework can't get reference to another model

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have Two Models that are relevant to my situation:

ApplicationUser ( Identity Framework ) and Room,

That's the Properties of Room.cs in the Model folder:

```
   public class Room
   {
        public int RoomId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int EnterPrice { get; set; }
        public int UserDecisionTime { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Card> CardsDeck { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Card> CardsOnTable { get; set; }
        public int WhosTurnChairNumber { get; set; }
        public string Chair0_Id { get; set; }
        public string Chair1_Id { get; set; }
        public string Chair2_Id { get; set; }
        public string Chair3_Id { get; set; }
        public string Chair4_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Chair0 { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Chair1 { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Chair2 { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Chair3 { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationUser Chair4 { get; set; }
        public int Round { get; set; }
        public int PotOfChair0 { get; set; }
        public int PotOfChair1 { get; set; }
        public int PotOfChair2 { get; set; }
        public int PotOfChair3 { get; set; }
        public int PotOfChair4 { get; set; }
}
```

That's how Room looks like as a table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rooms] (
    [RoomId]              INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]                NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [EnterPrice]          INT            NOT NULL,
    [UserDecisionTime]    INT            NOT NULL,
    [WhosTurnChairNumber] INT            NOT NULL,
    [Round]               INT            NOT NULL,
    [PotOfChair0]         INT            NULL,
    [PotOfChair1]         INT            NULL,
    [PotOfChair2]         INT            NULL,
    [PotOfChair3]         INT            NULL,
    [PotOfChair4]         INT            NULL,
    [Chair0_Id]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Chair1_Id]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Chair2_Id]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Chair3_Id]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Chair4_Id]           NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Chair0_Id1]          NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [Chair1_Id1]          NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [Chair2_Id1]          NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [Chair3_Id1]          NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    [Chair4_Id1]          NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Rooms] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RoomId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Rooms_dbo.AspNetUsers_Chair0_Id1] FOREIGN KEY ([Chair0_Id1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Rooms_dbo.AspNetUsers_Chair1_Id1] FOREIGN KEY ([Chair1_Id1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Rooms_dbo.AspNetUsers_Chair2_Id1] FOREIGN KEY ([Chair2_Id1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Rooms_dbo.AspNetUsers_Chair3_Id1] FOREIGN KEY ([Chair3_Id1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Rooms_dbo.AspNetUsers_Chair4_Id1] FOREIGN KEY ([Chair4_Id1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[AspNetUsers] ([Id]) );


GO CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Chair0_Id1]
    ON [dbo].[Rooms]([Chair0_Id1] ASC);


GO CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Chair1_Id1]
    ON [dbo].[Rooms]([Chair1_Id1] ASC);


GO CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Chair2_Id1]
    ON [dbo].[Rooms]([Chair2_Id1] ASC);


GO CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Chair3_Id1]
    ON [dbo].[Rooms]([Chair3_Id1] ASC);


GO CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Chair4_Id1]
    ON [dbo].[Rooms]([Chair4_Id1] ASC);
```

Now, in the Room, I have a method that add users to a chair, for example I can:

```
SomeMethod(ApplicationUser user) {
    this.Chair0 = user;
}
```

(I also do db.SaveChanges() )
And when I look into View -> SQL Server Object Explorer, it really saves in Chair0_Id the user, but when I'm doing:

```
Room = db.Rooms.Find(id);
```

It doesn't show in Room.Chair0 the first ApplicationUser, why's that?

Comment: You might need to `Include()` the properties you want to get from other tables into the model object, they aren’t loaded by default. That is if this is Entity Framework

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen should I change from db.Rooms.Find(...) to db.Rooms.Include(a => a.ApplicationUser).Find(...) ? <-- this one doesn't work by the way.

Comment: What is the value of the `id` you are supplying, can you also try `FristOrDefault`. `Find()` will look for the value that matches the primary key of that table. are you actually supplying the primary key of the table?

Comment: @Bosco when I'm debugging, I can see the Room object that includes all correct details of the one he found by .Find(id), but it just doesn't seem to have anything ( null ) in Chair0, once I can clearly see it at the table at Chair0_Id